# Changing Parameters in FFmpeg while encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, shaka

I am using FFmpeg to create MPEG dash segments from my camera and playing it using Shaka Player. But I want to change the segment size (For example 2 seconds to 1 second) without creating a new process and without exiting the current process. Is there a change to change the parameter value in FFmpeg while the process is still running?

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1280x720  -rtbufsize 100M  -r 30  -i 0 -qscale 100 -g 1 -vcodec libx264 seg_duration 1 -f dash -use_timeline 0 -use_template 0 -single_file 0 ffmpeg.mpd
```

This is the command where I want to change the segment_duration to 2, without exiting the current process.

ie.

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1280x720  -rtbufsize 100M  -r 30  -i 0 -qscale 100 -g 1 -vcodec libx264 -seg_duration 2 -f dash -use_timeline 0 -use_template 0 -single_file 0 ffmpeg.mpd
```

Or is there any other MPEG DASH Encoder for this use case?